# Authentication for an "Editor" is not taken into account

Tags: docusignapi

In my DocuSign integration, I have successfully been able to set up authentication for any signer. I am now trying to set it up for the Editor of the package. While my Editor receives the signing email, when he clicks on the link to proceed to the signing ceremony, the authentication doesn't seem to work and instead of having to verify his identity, the document is displayed and ready to sign.
Is it a feature or a bug ? I was thinking maybe since the editor has to have a DocuSign account, hence any authentication is unnecessary ?

```
My JSON code below :
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": "John.Doe@mailinator.com",
  "recipientId": "2",
  "requireIdLookup": "True",
  "idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $",
  "customFields": [
    "PARTY-8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Editor should be prompted for ID check during the signing ceremony, if it was setup correctly during sending.

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) call for setting up Id check for the Editor. I have tried this in the Docusign Demo environment and it works fine for me.

```
{
    "recipients": {
        "editors": [
            {
                "name": "john smith",
                "email": "johnsmith@foo.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "requireIdLookup": "true",
                "idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $"
            }
        ]
    },
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Agreememt",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "documentBase64": "[Document bytes go here]"
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Envelope with id check enabled for Editore"
}
```

Comment: I've done some testing and I have found that my code is correct as it works if the Editor is not the account holder of the integration key used to create the transaction. Is that normal ?